# Filter Pandas Dataframe using an arbitrary number of conditions

Tags: python, pandas

I am comfortable with basic filtering and querying using Pandas. For example, if I have a dataframe called `df` I can do `df[df['field1'] < 2]` or `df[df['field2'] < 3]`. I can also chain multiple criteria together, for example:

`df[(df['field1'] < 3) & (df['field2'] < 2)]`.

What if I don't know in advance how many criteria I will need to use? Is there a way to "chain" an arbitrary number of these operations together? I would like to pass a list of filters such as `[('field1', 3), ('field2', 2), ('field3', 4)]` which would result in the chaining of these 3 conditions together.

Thanks!

Comment: An example might help

Comment: `mask = df['field1'] < 3; mask = mask & (df['field2'] < 2); mask = mask & df['field3'] < 4` etc. Then use `df[mask]`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The pandas Series objects have the less than, greater than, etc operations as methods you can call.  So `df['field1'] < 3` becomes `df['field1'].lt(3)`.  This is not terribly important, but it makes the code more readable.

To implement what you are asking, you can use the `reduce` function from functools, and the `and_` (equivalent of `&`) from the operator package.

```
from functools import reduce
from operator import and_

reduce(and_, (df.field1.lt(3), df.field2.lt(2), df.field3.lt(4)))
```

Comment: I think this is the cleanest approach, with the most straight-forward intent and least magic. Thanks!

Comment: This is also a very good approach!  However, the dynamism is lacking.  Also, I'd venture to evaluate over ndarrays rather than series.  And... you still need to utilize the result to filter the initial dataframe.  I'd use this as the actual solution, even if it's a tad less readable.  `df[reduce(and_, (df[t[0]].values < t[1] for t in c))]` where `c = [('field1', 3), ('field2', 2), ('field3', 4)]`

Answer (score 6):

**Approach 1**
Use `pd.DataFrame.query`

```
c = [('field1', 3), ('field2', 2), ('field3', 4)]
f = '{0[0]} < {0[1]}'.format

df.query(' & '.join(f(t) for t in c))
```

---

**Approach 2**

```
c = [('field1', 3), ('field2', 2), ('field3', 4)]

df[df[[t[0] for t in c]].lt([t[1] for t in c]).all(1)]
```

---

**Approach 3**
Create a `pd.Series` out of `c` and then compare

```
c = [('field1', 3), ('field2', 2), ('field3', 4)]

s = pd.Series(dict(c))

df[df[s.index].lt(s).all(1)]
```

Comment: amazing ...:-) LOL

Comment: Thanks for the well thought out response. I do like Approach 2, which I think is the best solution here behind that offered by James.

Comment: fantastic answer!

Answer (score 1):

Something like `add` then using `all`, you get the boolean You need

```
df1[['f1','f2','f3']].add([-2,-3,-4]).lt(0).all(1)
```

Comment: I like the concept.  You'd have to show how you subset `df` and grab `[-2, -3, -4]`

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame([np.arange(4),np.arange(3,7),np.arange(5,9)],
                  columns = ["field1","field2","field3","field4"])

f = [('field1', 3), ('field2', 4), ('field3', 5)]

mask = np.array([(df[i[0]] == i[1]) for i in f])

# 1 True is enough:
df[mask.any(axis=0)]  # [False  True False] in this sample

# All must be true
df[mask.all(axis=0)]  # [False  True False] in this sample
```

Df looks like this:

```
   field1  field2  field3  field4
0       0       1       2       3
1       3       4       5       6
2       5       6       7       8
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that `reduce( (lambda x, y: x & (df[y[0]]<y[1])), list_of_filters )` will do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the conditions and iteratively build a mask by `&`ing (logical and) the boolean masks together

```
def chain_lt(df, conditions):
    for i, (field, val) in enumerate(conditions):
        res = df[field] < val
        if i == 0:
            msk = res
        else:
            msk &= res
    return df[msk]
```